# Is there such a thing as a clear both for CSS column styling?

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a parent element and it has column-count: 2 and i want the last p element in this container to take up the entire width of the parent container. But the column-count: 2 forces the last p element to appear in the 2nd column.

See here: https://image.prntscr.com/image/0b84d54f6c894b4183dd3d33205a9a43.png

Is there such a thing as a clear: both for column-count like how it would be used in floats?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to add styles to the last

element, you can use this selector

```
.columns-2 .p:nth-last-child(1){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Target the last p element using:

```
.columns-2 .p:nth-last-child(1){ column-span: all }
```

**column-span** property lets you specify how many columns the element should span.